# Call Facebook API with promise

Tags: javascript, promise, facebook-javascript-sdk

I installed: npm facebook-login and it works OK (returns the Facebook token and user id), but it does not have interface to the 'api' function.
So I added it to the script, but when I call it, it returns an error:

[image]

```
fb_login = () =>
{
  log('fb_login')
  api.whenLoaded().then(() =>
  {
    log('loaded!');
    api.login(["email","public_profile"]).then((response) =>
    {
      log('return from facebook');
      log(response);
      api.api('/me').then((response) =>
      {
        log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: which line of your code is responsible for this error? also, what did you add to make code that works (according to your opening statement) stop working? Also, are you using https://www.npmjs.com/package/facebook-login ? last published 4 years ago, and the github page no longer exists?

Comment: `return` `api....` from your callbacks. This will build the Promise chain.

Comment: What I wrote is not that it stopped working, but that it works till I get the response (token) from the login. When I call the api.api it crashes with that error.
I know that there is no github page, but I couldn't find something else.
I tried the "react-facebook-login" but it doesn't show my button.

Answer (score 0):

This npm is not working, but I just implmemnted th FB api from the SDK and it simple and straight forward.